# How to pass parameter to a bash function from shell

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

I have the following function defined in `.bash_aliases`

```
findphp () {
    find -name '*.php' -exec grep -H  --color "$@" "{}" \;
}
```

It allows me to run something like `findphp 'function x'` to find all references to `function x` in php files

Now I want to pass the file type to search, example js, css, ctp as a parameter in bash

I defined the follwing function and sourced .bash_aliases

```
myfind () {
    find -name '*.$1' -exec grep -H  --color "$2" "{}" \;
}
```

But it's not working, I tried single quotes, double quotes around the positional parameters
with no avail.

How could I define a function that takes the file extension and search string as arguments from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes prevent variable expansion. Use `"*.$1"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
findphp () {
    find . -name "*.$1" -exec grep -H --color "${@:2}" "{}" \;
}
```

or

```
findphp () {
    find . -name "*.$1" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H --color "${@:2}"
}
```

if you want the filenames too